# dell e5420 ubuntu laptop fan not fast enough for TF2

Tags: 16.04, dell, games, steam, fan

***problem  ***
cooling is too passive for my needs.

i have a dell e5420 laptop running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS that I use for light Steam gaming,(team fortress 2) but Ubuntu doesn't have a advanced fan and power settings like windows7/8.1 does. [ windows settings> power settings> advanced power settings> {list} > CPU fan%]

I would like to make the CPU fan spin faster than low/ idle overall (or spin up sooner)  for better cooling ether through software,terminal commands,or BIOS/UEFI editing if actually necessary.

***what I have done so far to attempt to fix this ***

- I have installed p sensor to watch temps.
- acquired a Targus chill mat.
- acquired a USB bendy fan to assist the chill mat.
- turned all in game settings down to super low.
- installed ThinkFan

*foot notes*
I am familiar to PC hardware (high school CompTIA A+ class) and software and I have torn this PC apart top to bottom twice.

my PC is ***not *** overheating just obviously toasty and I want the CPU fan to do a better job like it does in windows.  I have cleaned the heat sinks and applied new thermal paste.

***bios version A09***

Answer (score -1):

2 tips...

1. I'm not sure what BIOS you have, but if there are options for fan control, thermal profile, etc... Play with the settings... it is possible that your BIOS controls your fan speed, not your OS, and if that's the case then whatever program you install, it doesn't matter it won't change anything...
2. Get some machine oil, disassemble the fan if possible, (it often has a C shaped thing keeping it form falling apart at the back side under a sticker) clean it(it may have so dried shit inside), and put a drop of machine oil(mineral oil, or motor oil is fine) as you re-assemble it... Cooking oil will block it in time it's not like machine oil, don't use cooking oil or olive oil... I've done that many times, no fan has ever failed me. :) Press fitted, fans suck, cause you can't really disasemble it.

Comment: I have BIOS version A09

Comment: in legacy mode not UEFI

Comment: I have installed Thinkfan

Comment: I have installed Thinkfan 9.02.1

Comment: well shit.... i have installed thinkfan it made the problem worse. then sudo apt install thinkfan  and now the fan doesn't spin at ALL HELP!!!

Comment: well shit.... i have installed thinkfan it made it worse. that made a  non problem from a molehill to  mountain  . then sudo apt install thinkfan  and now the fan doesn't spin at ALL HELP!!!  (it spins up to to max and then off.     f###  me)

Comment: DON'T PANIC! Get a live disk, and if that program is the issue it should spin booting from the live disk... otherwise the problem is with the fan, or with something on the motherboard which controls it(which sucks big time)...

Comment: all righty then...